# Is there any way to stop MediaRecorder object after a single image from video frame captured while used in the chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**Here is my chrome extension code which captures screens.** 
**I want to stop the object after it has captured one frame using the MediaRecoder but it fails to stop from `dataavailable`**

```
if (localStorage.getItem('EventAgeStamps')) {
        var EventAgeStampsObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('EventAgeStamps'));
        var capturetime = new Date();
        var capturemin = capturetime.getMinutes();
        var seconds = capturetime.getSeconds();
        var screens = EventAgeStampsObj.screens;

        for (i = 0; i < screens.length; i++) {
            var j = 0;
            if ((capturemin == screens[i]) && (seconds > 15 && seconds < 17)) {
                IsPause = false;
                var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'video/webm'});
                // mediaRecorder.start(5000);
                if (mediaRecorder.state == 'inactive')
                    mediaRecorder.start(5000);
                else if (mediaRecorder.state == 'paused')
                    mediaRecorder.resume(5000);

                mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event = > {
                    if(event.data && event.data.size > 100000
            )
                {
                    file = new File([event.data], getFileName('mp4'), {
                        type: 'video/mp4'
                    });
                    if (j == 0) {
                        IsPause = true;
                        CrossPlatformScreens(file, j);
                    }
                    j++;
                    mediaRecorder.pause();
                    mediaRecorder = null;
                }
            })
                ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you just want one frame, why do you want a video? Would be far easier to have a still image.

Comment: hey @Kaiido   i have update my question.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question: Why do you want a video made of a single frame? Not only I doubt any browser will be able to generate it, but I also doubt you'll find many players that will be able to read it. If you just want a single frame, then take still picture, not a video. => Don't use a MediaRecorder but an [ImageCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture/grabFrame)

Comment: @Kaiido as i need to capture image from cross platform(other application,desktop) etc that's why i'm using MediaRecorder.

Comment: ... A MediaRecorder records a MediaStream into either a video or an audio fle. If you want a still image, then don't use a MediaRecorder but an ImageCapture object...